# Integral by parts?

Tags: integration

Let $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow {\mathbb R}_+$ be a density function with finite expectation. This is,

$$\int_{\mathbb R}x f(x)dx<\infty.$$

Suppose that we want to integrate $I(a)=\int_a^{\infty} x f(x)dx$ by parts. So, we proceed as usual by defining $u=x$, $dv= f(x)dx$, $du = dx$, $v=P(x)=\int f(x)dx$ (the primitive), then

$$I(a)=x P(x)\Big\vert_a^{\infty} - \int_a^{\infty}P(x)dx.$$

In general, we do not know the primitive $P$ but I wonder if there is a connection between $I$ and $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$, the cumulative distribution function? For example, if $f(x)=e^{-x}$, then $P(x)=-e^{-x} = F(x)-1$.

This is, can we write $I$ in terms of $F$ in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P$ is not "the" primitive but *a* primitive, since you can add any constant to it. The particular $P$ that you chose differs from $F$ only by such an additive constant, since $F$ is also a primitive – a particular one that vanishes at $-\infty$. If you had a proper integral, you could indeed use $F$ and get

$$\int_a^bxf(x)\mathrm dx=x F(x)\Big\vert_a^b - \int_a^bF(x)\mathrm dx\;.$$

However, if you integrate to $\infty$, both of these terms diverge, so this doesn't work any more. In this case, you need the one primitive that vanishes at $\infty$, and that's precisely the one that you used.